# process from console compared to winform

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

The following console application runs ok - I was surprised it did not error.

```
class DelegateExperiments
{

    //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    //open notepad when the console begins
    //create an event that fires and writes "Notepad closed" in the console
    //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    //instance variables of the form
    private const string helloText = "hello world";
    private const string exitText = "you just closed notepad";
    private Process myProcess;
    //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<        


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(helloText);

        DelegateExperiments myInstance;
        myInstance = new DelegateExperiments();
        myInstance.Foo();

        Console.Read();
    }

    void Foo()
    {

        myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"notepad.exe";
        myProcess.Exited += MyProcessExited;
        myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        //myProcess.SynchronizingObject = this;
        myProcess.Start();

    }

    private void MyProcessExited(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exitText);
    }


}
```

If I try to do something similar with a winform i.e write a message back to a label on the form then it's more complicated and needs the line `myProcess.SynchronizingObject = this;` to work. Why should they be different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Console` class was intentionally written to be thread safe.  You can call it from any thread.  It will even make sure to not to 'overlap' calls from different threads.  `Console.Write/WriteLine` is atomic.  This is because Console is designed to interact with a shell, and one major *purpose* of a shell is to be able to gather input from multiple *processes*.  It's a decent amount of work to have it be able to do that, but it needed to be done for it to realistically serve its purpose.

GUI objects, such as labels, were not designed with that in mind.

Comment: +1 even though Write/WriteLine is not atomic. Not even by a long shot. Atomic operations are only the assembly operations: Add, Sub, Mov, Jz, Cmp, etc...

Comment: If you have a writeline that prints out "hello " and another that prints "world " you will get either "hello world" or "world hello".  You won't get "helworldlo" or something like that.  For that reason you can say that `Console.Write` is atomic.  It is not inherently atomic, it is atomic because locks or other similar mechanisms are used to ensure that it's atomic.  You can have more than single assembly operations be atomic.

Comment: In this case, he meant thread-wise. I was talking about processor-wise.

Comment: [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_operation).  Most importantly see my example.  If we assume that the method is called at almost the same time from two threads then from the point of view of the caller it will appear as if one ran in entirety before the other started, and they won't intermingle.  See the example I gave in my last comment for why this is important for Console.WriteLine and what it would mean if it wasn't atomic.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Actually, it's not just thread wise.  It even applies to multiple processes.  That's the way most shells are designed; they can support interaction with multiple processes writing to STOUT and not end up just printing garbage.

Comment: @Servy The term "Thread safe" contains the term "Process safe" within it, by nature. But anyway, we were talking about different kind of 'atomic', so that is it. Good answer :)

Comment: @YoryeNathan (glad you two kissed and made up :))

Answer (score 0):

In WinForms, all access to UI elements must be on the dedicated UI thread. See section 1.2.1 [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18702/Threading-in-NET-and-WinForms).

As the documentation says:

> When the Exited event is handled by a visual Windows Forms component,
>   such as a Button, accessing the component through the system thread
>   pool might not work, or might result in an exception. Avoid this by
>   setting SynchronizingObject to a Windows Forms component, which causes
>   the methods handling the Exited event to be called on the same thread
>   on which the component was created.

Comment: The question is *why* do GUIs need to all be touched from a single thread.

Comment: It was actually more specific - why you need to set myProcess.SynchronizingObject - and the quote I pasted explains that this causes the handlers to execute on the same thread as the UI. You can argue that the answer is too specific, so go ahead.

Comment: All right, the answer is too specific, and doesn't give any meaningful insight as to why it's important for GUI apps to have a UI thread while a Console app doesn't have a 'console' thread.